# jspdf doesn't render at proper height and width in pixels

Tags: reactjs, jspdf

I have a useEffect hook in React that converts my page into a pdf. I can't get it to convert the whole page, and only the whole page, into the pdf using the correct pixel measurements. The width and height are always way too small. When I zoom in and out in the browser, this affects the aspect ratio of the pdf.

How do I fix the width and height to be the same width and height as the original page in pixels, and make the aspect ratio always 1?

The hook converts to png, then pdf and the png part seems fine?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (reportRef.current) {
        let node = reportRef.current;
        let reportHeight = reportRef.current.offsetHeight
        console.log("REPORT HEIGHT", reportHeight)

        htmlToImage.toPng(node)
        .then(function (dataUrl) {
            const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'px', [reportHeight, 555]);
            pdf.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', 0, 0);
            pdf.save("download.pdf"); 
        })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });}
}, [reportRef])
```

This code renders the right width, but cuts off the image:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    if (reportRef.current) {
        let node = reportRef.current;
        let reportHeight = reportRef.current.offsetHeight * 0.7
        let reportWidth = reportRef.current.offsetWidth*0.7
        console.log("REPORT HEIGHT", reportHeight)

        htmlToImage.toPng(node)
        .then(function (dataUrl) {
            const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'px', [11000, 555]);

            pdf.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', 0, 0, reportWidth, reportHeight);
            pdf.save("download.pdf"); 
        })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });}
}, [reportRef])
```